# Why php includes doesn´t processes accents right?

Tags: php, include, diacritics

As explained here ([PHP Include and accents (They show up as �)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867771/php-include-and-accents-they-show-up-as)) php has a strange behavior processing the accents. My question is Why?

I mean: I have a simple utf-8 charset page. With this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <?php include ('file.php');?>
```

The included file just says: "Administración." It has no charset, just header tags (h2, h3...), and some links. Like this:

```
<h2>Administración</h2>
```

So, there is no charset conflict. Are not they supposed that the include files are just ***included***?

The previous question was answered with some fix to the problem, but my question is Why PHP behaves this way?

Comment: Every file has a charset. Is it an ASCII text file, or a UTF-8 text file, or some other encoding?

Comment: use `&#243;` http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: Jordan: Hey, that´s interesting. I am playing with Intype, wich lets you select the charset in the bottom menu. It was UTF-8-Plain previously, I changed to UTF-8, and now it works pretty well. It WAS a charset conflict. How can I do the same thing in other editors, how do I know the default charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer you new questions (from your comment):

> How can I do the same thing in other
>   editors, how do I know the default
>   charset?

default-charset and charset for every single file can be set in almost every code-editor i know - where exactly depends on the editor. simply take a look into the manual/documentation of your editor for that.

Comment: oezi: That´s seems to be right. Working in NotPad++ I see that it has an option of Encoding, I think is a matter of been aware of matching encodings between documents. (And working with editors that let you set the correct option) Thanks for your help.