# Converting stranging characters extracted from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some problems extracting data from a mysql database. It contains some text in spanish, and I retrieve some weid chars when I do a query via php.

The text seems fine when I do query via mysql terminal.

**Text extracted from php**

> No se est� valorando lo suficiente el deporte y la situaci�n es muy
>   jodida

**Text from mysql terminal**

> No se está valorando lo suficiente el deporte y la situación es muy jodida

**Extraction code**

```
$db = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $bd );

$query = "select * from news limit 10";

$res = $db->query( $query );
$arr = [];
while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ){
   $arr[] = $row;
}

return $arr;
```

What can I do to change this chars for a correct value.

Thanks, Ismael.

Comment: i believe this has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867771/php-include-and-accents-they-show-up-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set names` for codepage selection.

Comment: I used this in mysql console `SET NAMES utf8;` and it gives me the same result.

Comment: It's mean that code page of a console is not a utf8.
Try `set names cp1252`